# Rectification of an image by using texture projection

Tags: ios, graphics, computer-vision, textures, gpu

I need to rectify an image with texture projection on GPU (GLSL/shaders), do you have any resources/tutorials/insights to share? I have the 3D pose of the camera that created the image and the image itself as an input.

My images are 640x480 and from what I understand the buffer memory on iPhone 4S (one of the target devices) is less than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the size is not a problem. Also to do rectification, once you have the homography that provides the rectification, use it in the vertex shader to multiply all of the initial 2D homogeneous coordinates.